# Problem creating REST API With JSON Server

Tags: json-server

I am going through the tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x3NAo8zqdmo
to set up json server. I am able to install it, however when I run the command json-server --watch db.json, I keep getting error 
events.js:183
throw er: //unhandled 'error' event

I googled the error, there is nothing running on port 3000 . I even rebooted my machine but error did not go away.
I reinstalled json-server using my company's proxy settings to go behind proxy settings since I had to do that for angular cli installation, but still error is not going away. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by changing the port with command
json-server -p 4000 db.json